# How does oil inhibit head formation? Do citrus oils inhibit head formation?

Tags: head, head-retention

A two part question:

1. How does oil inhibit formation of head in beer? Homebrewers take as gospel that oil-containing ingredients such as nuts will negatively impact head. But I can't find any articles or other materials explaining how and why this is true. I am trying to understand the chemistry of how this works.
2. Do citrus oils (from citrus zest or orange peel) inhibit head formation? Randy Mosher says that [in his experience citrus oils do not affect head](https://allaboutbeer.net/article/is-that-an-orange-in-my-beer/).

Comment: Hop oils increase head retention.  How does that effect the gospel?

Answer (score 1):

[Here's a scientific publication](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15491178) that may interest you.

(from the abstract) *"Microscopic observations have shown that the fast antifoams rupture the foam films by the so-called "bridging" mechanisms, which involve the formation of oil bridges between the two surfaces of the foam film."*